# creating twitch and discord with api

Tags: bots, twitch, twitch-api

I have started to learning coding stuff a few months ago and I'm new at this kind of stuff. I want to learn doing bots for twitch and I search it on youtube. I found some videos about that but everybody using something called "tmi.js" and I don't know and I couldn't find how to use is. can someone help me about it, thanks.

I searched "tmi.js" It on google but I couldn't find something.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.